# Node inspect wait for port to be free

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I use node inspect on my js.file but always get:

```
Timeout (2000) waiting for 127.0.0.1:9229 to be free
```

I've tried this solution https://github.com/nodejs/node-inspect/issues/48, but had no success. I use only CLI, it's cmder for Windows, if that matters. Node version is v10.16.3. I've ran

```
netstat -ano | findstr :9229
```

to find out how's keeping the port busy nd kill it by PID, but got no results.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing has been fixed in the `node-inspect` package, but this fix has not yet been added to your version of Node.js. Then, to solve this problem, you can use the `node-inspect` package separately. First you need to install it:

```
npm i -g node-inspect
```

After that you can use this module:

```
node-inspect app.js
```

Hope this solution helps you.